# A Div tag appended with html content (in DocumentFragment), but shows only inner text instead of result html

Tags: html, google-chrome, appendchild, plaintext

This issue is specific to Chrome, A response html (documentfragment) is resulted after xml and xsl parsed similar to the source : 
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_cdcatalog

I am doing exactly same for my scenario, i could debug div containing html ( for ex: a small table data), But after appending to existing Div, only text is shown on the webpage (as if inner text appended).

when inspected for element div (in DevTools), the html content is appended in the source. Interestingly,when I edit the html(say add border="1" for the table) and press enter, immediately the html content is shown properly on the web page.

Whats missing? Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem. 
This document fragment formed by xml and xsl merge, which was developed specific to IE, with xsl output-method="xml", this attribute is causing the transformed data as XML, not interpreted as HTML..so removed this attribute, may be defaulting output-method to HTML..so it shows as properly on webpage (as html, instead of text) in both Chrome and IE11+